# Date time format with TZ specfied with datetime in R( ISO 8601 )

Tags: r

I need to get current time in R in this particular format:

```
2014-01-07T14:57:55+05:30
```

`Sys.time()` seems to return in a different format than this. How do I exactly get this ?

Link to the format : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: See package `parsedate`

Comment: `strftime(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")`?

Comment: @J_F: Nope. He wants to _format_ the current time, not parse a date string.

Answer (score 2):

The function for converting/formatting a time string is `as.POSIXct` or `as.POSIXlt`.  The [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html) for these points to the docs for [strptime](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) for format symbols.  This reference indicates `%F` is the correct symbol for `ISO-8601` however, implementing that results in a format different from what you suggest.

```
> as.POSIXct(Sys.time(),format="%F")
[1] "2016-10-02 18:57:58 EDT"
```

I suspect looking at [strptime](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) you will find the combination necessary to output the exact format you need.

Comment: That is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your looking for?

```
format(Sys.time(), format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+01:00")
format(Sys.time(), format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

The meaning of the letters you find a the documentation of `strptime()` function

Comment: okay...i don't find a way to make the both dots between the offset hours and minutes. Is there a way??

Comment: Your edited answer is closer as `%z` is what R offers, even if it is without a `:` separating hours and minutes.